# cordova build issue - javac - version failed to run

Tags: java, android, cordova, mobile

I am facing the issue while I build the android. I installed java jdk properly.

[image]

Comment: Install JDK and set environment variables

Comment: I have installed JDK and set path. But still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

In path variable you have to give the both JDK and JRE path upto bin,

like this

path : ....;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;

coming to JAVA_HOME give the path upto JDK folder

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

u have given upto bin may be that's the issue.

If your cmd is open then close and open new cmd and do the operations

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I added java_home and path. but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @sathiya Steps to install cordova and APK generation, find the attachement here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h6InPOJrinEJDTYWjpYDefyH-3g9IAQC. That is JDK Related issue once make sure that u r giving correct path, simply execute HelloWorld.java and check. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I installed jDK Properly. but i build android it is showing failed to run javac.exe

Comment: getting error from this function - node_modules\cordova-android\bin\templates\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js                                                          then(function () {
        return Q.denodeify(child_process.exec)('javac -version')
            .

Comment: @sathiya, follow the steps mentioned in shared file. Thank you